# Pseudo element :after disapears on chrome mobile

Tags: android, html, ios, css, google-chrome

I have a page with navigation elements that I want to be hidden on the left/right of the page and shown when I hover an icon. I created the icons using the `:after` pseudo-element on the elements I want hidden. The solution works fine on tested desktop browser but fails on chrome mobile (even though the desktop version works fine).

I tested on both iOS and Android and none is able to display the `:after` pseudo-element. **BUT** if you happen to click at the location the `:after` is supposed to be, the menu reveals. So it seems that it only is a display issue.

I have created [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yr4zag6n/4/) to show the problem. I’ve added a bit of javascript just because it is on the real page but I don't think it is the cause of the issue.

What's even weirder is that, on iOS, both chrome and safari can display the `M` and `S` on the jsfiddle but fails at showing the icons on the real page. Chrome on Android fails to show the elements on jsfiddle too, though.

So, my question is, how can I display `:after` pseudo-elements on Chrome mobile or iOS browsers?

```css
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background: white;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

footer {
  padding: 10px;
}

section {
  background: white;
  margin: 350px 0px 0px;
  padding: 10px 10% 25px;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.19), 0px -10px 10px rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.23);
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: justify;
}

header div {
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
}

header nav {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 60%;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 100%;
  background: #BBBBBB;
  color: #324353;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 3;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

header nav:hover {
  right: 40%;
  box-shadow: 15px 0px 20px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.3);
}

header nav:after {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 15px;
  content: "M";
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  color: #324353;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 4 !important;
}

header nav:hover:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  content: "x";
}

header aside {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 60%;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 100%;
  background: #BBBBBB;
  color: #324353;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 3;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

header aside:hover {
  left: 40%;
  box-shadow: -15px 0px 20px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.3);
}

header aside:after {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 15px;
  content: "S";
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  color: #324353;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 4 !important;
}

header aside:hover:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  content: "x";
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div>
    <h1>
    Some Title
    </h1>
  </div>
  <nav>
    Some Menu
  </nav>
  <aside>
    Some Settings
  </aside>
</header>

<section>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam id faucibus sem. Nullam venenatis arcu massa, sit amet sodales dui dapibus sit amet. Nunc est elit, feugiat a molestie a, eleifend vitae diam. Sed eleifend eros vel nunc cursus gravida. Nulla magna dolor, finibus non dolor a, auctor porta diam. Proin a justo ultrices, semper dolor sit amet, maximus leo. Proin vehicula tincidunt tortor, gravida pellentesque risus sollicitudin vel. Cras lacinia luctus tellus in consectetur. Morbi facilisis nec justo ut condimentum. In semper vestibulum libero, non vestibulum lacus efficitur sed. Proin laoreet convallis tristique. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec porta ligula odio, quis hendrerit nisl accumsan ac. Mauris aliquam cursus ultricies. Curabitur luctus, mi auctor bibendum interdum, mi arcu luctus lorem, at ornare nunc felis et lorem. Maecenas ut hendrerit arcu.
</section>
<footer>Some footer text</footer>
```

Comment: Do you refer to the "x" icon? And you want it to appear on top of the slide menu.

Comment: @Pangloss No, I don't really care about the 'x'. What I want is that both 'M' and 'S' appear at all on chrome mobile (and possibly safari on iOS too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what's going on with the mobile browsers, but removing `overflow-y: auto;` from both `header nav` and `header aside` seems to be working.

But, if you do need the scrollbar, you can add another element (i.e. `<ul>`) into the `<nav>`.

```
header nav ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

See the **[updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yr4zag6n/7/)**.